# Mail attachment pdf file

Tags: php, email, pdf

I'm using html2pdf to generate a pdf file, and I will send it by mail attachement.

1- I've created a pdf file: works fine

2- I've saved it: works fine.

3- I've attached it for send mail but it doesn't work: I've received a mail with pdf attached but impossible to open it! (filesize < normal filesize). And when I resend a mail again, works fine !

Do you have any suggestions please?

My php code:

```
$filename='facture.pdf';
$mail_to = $email;
$subject = "Facture";
$random_hash = md5(time());
$headers = "From:" .$mailnotif." \r\nReply-To: mondmain.fr";
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
$path = 'http://mondmain.fr/Factures/'.$id.'/'.$filename.'';
$attachment = @chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($path)));
$message = "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n"
."Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-$random_hash\"\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--PHP-alt-$random_hash\r\n"
."Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

//Insert the plain text message.
$message .= strip_tags($subject);
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--PHP-alt-$random_hash\r\n"
."Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n" ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

//Insert the html message.
$message .= 'Bonjour,
Veuillez trouver ci-joint la facture correspondant à votre abonnement sur mondmain.fr.'
$message .="\r\n\r\n--PHP-alt-$random_hash--\r\n\r\n";

//include attachment
$message .= "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/doc; name=\"$filename\"\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"$filename\"\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/docx; name=\"$filename\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n\r\n";

$message .= $attachment;
$message .= "/r/n--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";

//send the email
mail( $mail_to, $subject , $message, $headers );
```

Comment: It would help a lot to see the code you use.

Comment: My code php is above, i can't add it in comment (long text) :)

Comment: in a same page php page1.php, i've  a link to page2.php(into i can generate and save pdf ) and in page2.php i 've an action to return on page1.php  and send mail ...

Comment: I edited your question/code. Next time, use proper indentation for `code`, being 4 spaces then line of code etc. @Nashen

Comment: I think you forgot to put a closing quote at the end of `$message .= "/r/n--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";` to make it as `$message .= "/r/n--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--"';` and it should work. @Nashen

Comment: but i haven't open a quote ' for $message .= "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n" ?

Comment: Yes there is, in `$message .= 'Bonjour,` @Nashen

Comment: excuse me Fred, it 'is a missing of copy/paste of code.   but 'is not work

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It wasn't that, it was something else. All details are in my answer below. @Nashen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(Tested and attachment received on a `SINGLE` run)**

You had some single quotes which should have been double quotes and did not close the text body with a semi-colon.

```
$message .= 'Bonjour, Veuillez trouver ci-joint la facture correspondant à votre abonnement sur mondmain.fr.'
```

Has been changed to: (with closing semi-colon)

```
$message .= "Bonjour, Veuillez trouver ci-joint la facture correspondant à votre abonnement sur mondmain.fr";
```

If what I posted below doesn't work, try replacing this line:

```
$attachment = @chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($path)));
```

with:

```
$attachment = @chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)));
```

which is what I used to test it with, since I do not have the same setup as you do, using an `$id` variable.

Rewrite: (Successfully tested with one of my PDF files)

```
<?php

$filename='facture.pdf';
$mail_to = $email;
$subject = "Facture";
$random_hash = md5(time());
$headers = "From:" .$mailnotif." \r\nReply-To: mondmain.fr";
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";

$path = 'http://mondmain.fr/Factures/'.$id.'/'.$filename.'';

$attachment = @chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($path)));
$message = "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n" ."Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-$random_hash\"\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--PHP-alt-$random_hash\r\n" ."Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n" ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

//Insert the plain text message.
$message .= strip_tags($subject);
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--PHP-alt-$random_hash\r\n"
."Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n" ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

//Insert the html message.
$message .= "Bonjour, Veuillez trouver ci-joint la facture correspondant à votre abonnement sur mondmain";
$message .="\r\n\r\n--PHP-alt-$random_hash--\r\n\r\n";

//include attachment
$message .= "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/doc; name=\"$filename\"\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"$filename\"\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/docx; name=\"$filename\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n\r\n";

$message .= $attachment;
$message .= "/r/n--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";

//send the email
mail( $mail_to, $subject , $message, $headers );
?>
```

Comment: yes, but is not work, filesize pdf attach=50k! impossible to open  file

Comment: What do you mean by `50k`? 50 Megabytes? @Nashen

Comment: If that's what you meant by 50k (50 MB), your server may be limiting your filesize and may be related to the upload max setting. Read this regarding file attachments: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_attachment @Nashen --- And you can read through this, where someone had a similar problem http://www.roundcubeforum.net/index.php?topic=2398.0

Comment: And here's another about `post_max_size = 1000M` at the bottom of that page, but do read all of it >>> https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1875365&start=0 @Nashen

Comment: OK. Well if it's not opening the file, then you need to check the filepath for it. At the bottom of the code, use `var_dump($path);` to see what values come up. @Nashen Put that just below `mail( $mail_to, $subject , $message, $headers );` and it will show you if something is set or not. I.e.: `$id` `$path` etc. It's obviously not finding your file with the path you're using. Plus see my answer about `If what I posted below doesn't work, try replacing this line:` for another way of doing it.

Comment: it's work fine now! it was a simple disorder  in calling  php classes  thank you Fred.

Comment: You're welcome. We can now close the question. @Nashen Please click the white checkmark next to my answer till it turns green.